# jQuery - hide & show li items that have a variable class

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a drop-down menu as an unordered list. When a category is selected, I only want the `li` with the same class as the value of the selection to remain visible.

I have tried using the `not` selector but I'm having trouble using it in combination with a variable class - that is also the same as the value of the selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chosenCat = $('select[name="mapCat"]').val();
    var className = $('#mapContent ul li.');
    $("#mapContent ul li").not("'.' +chosenCat").addClass("displayNone");   
});
```

I've been making edits but this jQuery snippet isn't working. How do I correctly write the variable I want to remain visible? Or is the error in the `val()` I'm pulling?

the HTML:

```
<select name="mapCat">
    <option value="opt0" selected="selected">SELECT A CATEGORY</option>
    <option value="opt1">UNIVERSITIES</option>
    <option value="opt2">HOSPITALS</option>
</select>
<div id="mapContent">
    <ul>
       <li class="opt1">University X</li>
       <li class="opt2">Hospital X</li>
       <li class="opt2">Hospital Y</li>
       <li class="opt1">University Y</li>
       <li class="opt1">University Z</li>
       <li class="opt2">Hospital Z</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS snippet:

```
.displayNone {
   display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
         $('select[name="mapCat"]').change(function(){
            var chosenCat =$(this).val();       
            $('#mapContent ul li').hide();
            $('#mapContent ul li.'+chosenCat).show();
         });
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need double `quotes` in `not()` selector as they will cause the *variable* to be treated as `string`.

```
$("#mapContent ul li").not('.' + chosenCat).addClass("displayNone");
```

The code you have will pass `'.' +chosenCat` in the not selector instead of passing `.opt0` or `.opt1` etc depending upon selection.

Also you probably need to do it on change event of the select, also if you just want to show and hide the you can use the show and hide function.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GSYD9/)**

```
$('select[name="mapCat"]').change(function(){
     var chosenCat = $(this).val();  
     $("#mapContent ul li").show()
     $("#mapContent ul li").not('.' + chosenCat).hide();   
});
```

Comment: great advice. thanks for the  demo. obviously, I'm new to query - I need to familiarize myself with more function options.